# TextLimit in TextField(value: format:) in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a problem because I can't set a character limit when using the value instead of text in a TextField. For example, I want to limit it to value < 50 and to prevent input after reaching that number. Is there any way to work around this? Funny thing that on iOS 17 this working out of the box.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @FocusState var isFocused: Bool
    @State var text = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                TextField("write text here...",
                          value: $text,
                          format: .number)
                .focused($isFocused)
                .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                .onChange(of: text) { _ in
                    if text > 50 {
                        text = 100
                    }
                }
            }
            .border(.black)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: "Funny thing that on iOS 17 this working out of the box." *What* is working on iOS 17?

Comment: And do you want to set a *character* limit (limit the number of characters) or a maximum numerical value that the user can enter?

Comment: both. because I want have textField with numbers and string formatter but when I try add text or value limit it doesn't work on iOS 15,16 but works correctly on 17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the specific TextField initializer you're using does not update the displayed value unless focus has been released. You can see this in this video, that once focus is released, the value is properly updated to 100:

[Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gIi7.gif)

Your best solution might be to use a different TextField initializer, and do manual number formatting:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @FocusState var isFocused: Bool
    @State var text: String = "0"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                TextField(text: $text, label: {
                    Text("write text here...")
                })
                .focused($isFocused)
                .keyboardType(.numberPad)
            }
            .onChange(of: text) { newValue in
                // remove all non-digits
                text = text.filter("0123456789".contains)
                if Int(newValue) ?? 0 > 50 {
                    text = "100"
                }
            }
            .border(.black)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```